# Typescript: preserve exact element type when storing value in array

Tags: typescript, merge, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Consider the following code with lodash merge:

```
  import { merge } from "lodash";
    
  type Cfg = {
        a: number
        b: number
        c: number
    };
    
  const cfg: Cfg = merge({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 4 });
```

This gives no error, because merge function preserves exact typings for all passed objects and resulting `cfg` is an intersection of all these types (type of `cfg` becomes a `{a: number} & {b: number} & {c: number}`, so it is compatible with `Cfg` ). If I pass to `merge` some property, that is not on `Cfg`, or miss some of the required properties, I will get an error.

But now, I need to do the same, but storing somewhere each of the objects beforehand.

Something like:

```
import { merge } from "lodash";
    
  type Cfg = {
    a: number
    b: number
    c: number
  };

  const arr: Partial<Cfg>[] = [];

  function addPartial<ArgType extends Cfg>(partial: ArgType) { arr.push(partial); };

  addPartial({ a: 1 });
  addPartial({ b: 2 });
  addPartial({ c: 3 });

  const cfg: Cfg = merge(...arr);
```

Now by setting explicit type of array elements to `Partial<Cfg>`, I lose the exact type, so the resulting type that I get for `cfg` will be `Partial<Cfg>`, which of course does not satisfy `Cfg`.

Is there any way to gradually add up these partials, storing them without losing their type, so that it could be proved that cfg satisfies Cfg type?

Comment: I assume `function addPartial` and `store(..)` are the same function? and it is very difficult in general, you'd have better luck just doing something like `partcfg1 = {}; let partcfg2 = merge(partcfg1, {..}); partcfg3 = merge(partcfg2, {..})` then the typing would just work, getting the append method to encode type information like this is really hard.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have corrected it.
Thanks for response!
Yep, hard enough in fact for me to post a question on StackOverflow)
In fact this is highly simplified example from what I have in my JS module for config management, that I now try to port to Typescript.

Comment: One of the features is that it allows you to "extend" configuration with many "chunks", or "partials" (so you can pass your config around and extend it from different places), for each of those you can set a priority, and then when you decide to "build" your configuration all those chunks are merged in priority order with merge tool such as lodash merge.

So, I cannot just merge them at once, as it will defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is not really, but specific cases have usable work arounds.  You are asking for something along the lines of [mutating type annotation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30406#issuecomment-475861672) which hasn't been implemented to the degree you are looking for.

The only way to change the type of some random field after call to arbitrary function is for that function to be a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), so one option is to have a not actually used variable that is repeatedly asserted to contain the relevent fields then use it's type for the final merge: ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsQYBzEAHgBUA%20ACgDpHYSBnALnkoG0BdASg6UA3ACgRAenHxUIAG7F4UTMigQIAT3jIWIYABp4AK20ZpIXbqQ4Y8DOoAOIFrZyKwYZAWTQMCOcU0wVQgXRWBgAAVYbFURMDwWU3sWZF0cAH0wRBIOAG8AX3gAXngCsTtHeABhbOLSkXhGxQ5UTwAjYgamtpb2zqb4MF6CDpgu-NE4hNNYGA4omBiIchqSal463knJWwALBAADAB9q7IP4LGdtEBQQxGsL1F81S5BUHQMAdywMXaMTeARLBgADWK2yegA0tRHs9Xu8EMAcE5UAByUwg1A4T7wT67KAYkDqZywBCyVRYYBaJ5YEK-ImKOBuDAqNSaEhYeSoegiFDobB4MKRaJYVTkSHwEAAD18qGAzhBRJwiFOa1oUHCP1wqHmwLBqyhMJOBvg9nsRWSqSRmWyAkULB0i2cZouziBoPBJENuS6jVm9Hs2l26s1AtQfFE%20TEGuFi1FEFouSgHAArPkDJa0jaSHwRDGFktEz14GmMyks1kcxIpPmRapE0MS%20nTeXrZXc1N3qZbhBMnhEFgcqq6kRSCAGEwYDA%20PbbA4QMqW1aMpWhEA))

```
declare function merge<T>(...args: T[]): T;

// never actually used, just needed for types to accumulate every call to addPartial
const psuedo_cfg: {} = {}

type Cfg = {
    a: number
    b: number
    c: number
  };

const arr: Partial<Cfg>[] = [];

// the `| Cfg` is useful for intellisense, with just Pick<Cfg,K> intelisense doesn't know what keys are valid until they are actually given.
function addPartial<K extends keyof Cfg>(addition: Pick<Cfg,K> | Cfg, pp=psuedo_cfg): asserts pp is Pick<Cfg,K>{
    arr.push(addition);
}

addPartial({a: 5}, psuedo_cfg)
addPartial({b: 5}, psuedo_cfg)
// addPartial({c: 5}, psuedo_cfg)

const full_config: Cfg = merge(...arr) as typeof psuedo_cfg;
```

Comment: Wow now that is ingenious!

It works, but I cannot understand a couple of things:

1) if `pseudo_cfg` is the default for pp parameter, why do we have to pass it every time? Doesn't work without it, though.

2) how does `asserts pp is K` produce intersection type? I though that asserted type should be replaced if we're doing `asserts` multiple times, but it seems that types stack up instead?

Comment: @YaroslavLarin 1) I think it's just that asserting default value was not considered as a use case so it wasn't implemented (typescript never has to look at default arguments except to infer parameter type so this'd be a special case) 2) `asserts` always takes an intersection of the current type with the asserted type, you would expect a variable of type `'a' | 'b' | number` asserted to be `string` to end up `'a' | 'b'`, intersection is much preferable to replacement.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. In this case I guess we can discard default altogether.

We can also further improve addPartial function and make it work with nested properties by doing
```ts
function addPartial<K extends DeepPartial<Cfg>>(
  addition: K,
  pc: typeof pseudoCfg,
): asserts pc is K {
  arr.push(addition)
}
```
No need in `Pick<Cfg,K> | Cfg` in this case. 
`DeepPartial` is a recursive version of Partial (can be found in `ts-essentials` types library)

Comment: @YaroslavLarin the reason I don't use `Partial` or `DeepPartial` is that it allows passing `undefined` or `null` values with strict null check on. It's entirely possible this isn't an issue for you but in general the generic to use `Pick<Cfg,K>` is more accurate when possible to use. anyway remember to upvote and or accept if this works for you :) Cheers!

Comment: Already upvoted, it just doesn't show up yet because I have less then 15 reputation. Thanks for the help again!